# Replacing Vue Components with Blade Components, Is is fully possible?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am planning to replace a Laravel App with a Vue frontend by blade components and blade views entirely, but I have one simple issue. Now the problem is while most of what I could achieve using Vue or some other javascript framework can be done using blade, but, what is the "right" or maybe standard way of dealing with making the ui reactive without using any other js framework or writing vanilla js. Or is it the only way possible? Or do I *need* to use vue js with or without balde components to achieve these kind of event handling or making ui reactive. And if the solution is to use vanilla js, what is the *right* way to approach it?

For example as it is written in the vue docs, a menu button could easily be handled using as such:

```
<div id="example-3">
  <button v-on:click="say('hi')">Say hi</button>
  <button v-on:click="say('what')">Say what</button>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#example-3',
  methods: {
    say: function (message) {
      alert(message)
    }
  }
})
```

The biggest question is *can blade components alone replace vue js components?*

Comment: You're going to require some flavor of JavaScript (a framework, library or vanilla etc.) to provide interactive pages. Blade/HTML can't do it alone.

Comment: Take a look at [livewire](https://github.com/livewire/livewire) It provide reactivity within blade by rendering partials. To go deeper, I recommend you to look at the [TALL stack](https://tallstack.dev)

Answer (score 0):

Vue is providing the reactivity on the frontend without requiring the page to refresh or the replacment of DOM segments with responses from AJAX requests.

`Blade` cannot 1-for-1 replace `Vue`

Think of `Blade` as a purely server-side PHP tool that helps you build and render a HTML document.

`Vue` on the other hand is a JavaScript framework for help building a clientside application.

---

**TL/DR** - `Blade` does not equal `Vue`. Which you chose should be dependent on the usecase.

Static content, use `Blade`. Reactive content, use `Vue`.